# Image processing performance in Android

Tags: android, android-image

I am trying to perform a pack of operations to my image, such as:

- apply photoshop curves (change pixel values and use bmp.setPixels())
- apply brightness/contrast changes (using ColorMatrix and paint.setColorFilter)
- apply saturation (with ColorMatrix, too)
- blur image (using bmp.setPixels())

and more.

Problem is that when I trying to apply 3 or 4 or 5 operations to one image, it takes a lot of time (10-12 seconds on my HTC Desire) and it is not good.
I am searching for a good way to improve perfomance of image processing.
Is it possible?

Comment: Use native code ?  http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: I don't know how large the image is. But taken from a modern smartphone, it could be 8 million pixels easily. So 10 seconds isn't that long if you keep that in mind.

Comment: and what do you think about opengl?